# Not able to install PostgreSQL 9.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.4

When I try to install PostgreSQL 9.4.+ on Ubuntu, it is installing version 9.3.9. I have used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Then I have tried with `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4`.
But that gave me an error like "package not found".

How can I install 9.4 on Ubuntu?

Distribution details:

- Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
- Description:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Release:  14.04
- Codename: trusty

Answer (score 6):

14.04 shipped with PostgreSQL 9.3, so that's what you're going to get if you use Ubuntu's repositories.

If you want PostgreSQL 9.4 or newer releases you need to add a 3rd party package repository, like the official PostgreSQL repositories from http://apt.postgresql.org/ . See the instructions there for details.

(You should also probably read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)